# What is difference between "xxx, although yyy" and "although yyy, xxx"?

Tags: differences

For instance:

1. I hate it, although it is funny.
2. Although it is funny, I hate it.

Is there difference?

Comment: The primary difference involves the note that the observation ends on ("it is funny" versus "I hate it"). The elements are identical, but the phrase that will be freshest in the listener's ears (or the reader's eyes) is strikingly different in the two formulations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of the truth values of the sentences, there is no difference between the two things. However, in terms of the presentation of the information, the information that's most important would be put at the end of the sentence.

So in:

> I hate it although it is funny

The concession that it is funny is presented as being interesting or important.  But in:

> Although it's funny, I hate it.

... the fact that you hate it is emphasised more.

Answer (score 0):

If you begin with main clause, do not use comma.

"I hate it although it is funny".

If you begin with subordinate clause, use comma.

"Although it is funny, I hate it".